# Cross Project TFS Work Item

Tags: tfs, tfs-workitem, tfs-2010

I am working with a 2010 TFS system where there are many projects and the team works across these projects.  The issue I am having is that it seems Work Itmes are tied to a Project and there is no way to enter a "master" where I would select the project from a drop down.  Note these projects are within a Project Collection.

Is there a way to do this or should we have put all this team's projects within one TFS project and get this for "free."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no cross project work item, and you don't need it, because work item belong to one project, but team can still working on multiple projects and get their work items in one query by selecting 2 or more projects in the query.
[image]

Comment: The image, as scaled, is not readable. Could you do an image just of the top left where all the relevant information is?

Comment: Thank you for the information. I was not too worried about the reporting, I was hoping for a one stop shop for adding or more importantly moving items.  For example, since there are dependencies between projects an item that may seem to be a problem with project X may actually be due to project Y after inspection.  Instead of just changing a drop down, I would then have to close out the original work item and create a new one.  It seems to me the best way to do this is to have each project as it's own folder within a larger project, but I am not sure that is how Microsoft intended TFS to work.

Comment: Meanwhile.  Work items from multiple projects in a single hierarchy/report within Jira are crazy simple... Hope to see vso catch up soon!